# Is there a device manager for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a Debian/Ubuntu package that serves as a device manager, an application that allows me to see and modify hardware on my machine (ie. hard drives, network cards, etc.) through a visual interface.

I searched for one and found `gnome-device-manager`, however it seems to have been discontinued and is removed from the official repositories. I also searched the Ubuntu Software Centre but could not find any.

Does anybody know any alternatives I can use?

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but `lshw` is useful in aggregating your current hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no application that lets you both view and manage your hardware.

While tools like `hardinfo` may be able to give you an abstraction of the hardware in your computer, it cannot disable, change or install a driver.

You will have to resort to command-line tools like modprobe, modinfo and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no unified hardware management.

The network manager is there by default and you can install `gparted` for hard drive management.

`baobab` (Listed as Disk Usage Analyzer) is also useful for drive usage.

You can benchmark your drives and view smart data with `palimpsest`.

You can configure screen resolution through system settings or proprietary apps.

CPU scaling was available as a gnome 2 panel applet, don't know what's replacing it.

If you have a complex audio card, you might need `alsamixer` to ajust inputs / outputs volume.